pydevd or debugpy Can I restart the debugging service without restarting the python interpreter
I am using an embedded Python interpreter in my own project, and I am also familiar with the process of starting a debugging service within the process where the Python interpreter is running. Clearly, I have successfully enabled the debugging service. However, there is a pain point with using this debugging feature: I have to establish the debugging service at the very beginning of the program, and I cannot "dynamically" disable the debugging service. I must restart the program, pass parameters to disable the debugging server, and then the program starts as a normal Python interpreter without the debugging service.
So, my question is: How can I disable my debugging service (pydevd or debugpy) in my process without shutting down the Python interpreter, such that the effects of these debugging services are completely eliminated from my process? Furthermore, how can I restart the debugging service without shutting down the Python interpreter?
I have tried pydevd.stoptrace, and technically, it works, but when I try to enable the debugging service again, it always tells me that a certain port is already in use (in fact, I used netstat -nao to check the port usage and could not find the port it mentioned; I am not sure if this is a bug in pydevd). I also tried modifying the internal code of debugpy, but I ended up back at the same place (it always tells me that the port is occupied).
Additionally, I am not even sure if this approach fully clears the effects of the debugging service from the process. :(
I know this is difficult, maybe? After all, when we debug most programs, we usually start the debugging service beforehand, and to run the so-called "release" mode, we must restart the program. But I still want to ask if there is an easy way to achieve this?
